# WiFiAdapter.ScanAsync() failing after losing established WiFi connection

Tags: c#, uwp, async-await, hololens

I'm working with the Windows.Devices.WiFi API for a UWP HoloLens App. I'm scanning the available networks as often as possible (calling Scan() every frame) by using a boolean that's set to false right before calling the "await ScanAsync()", and set to true after the async is being finished, which leads to calling ScanAsync() everytime it just finished, which works well. Something like this:

```
public async Task Scan()
{
    if (IsReady)
    {       
        IsReady = false;
        try
        {
            await MyWiFiAdapter.ScanAsync();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            string fail = e.ToString();
            Success = false;
        }
        IsReady = true;
    }
}
```

If my desired SSID is available, I connect to it using "await WiFiAdapter.ConnectAsync()", which works just fine (I'm checking it by connecting the HoloLens to a hotspot of my smartphone).

Now to the bug:

Connecting to my hotspot with the HoloLens is working. If I then disable my hotspot, the HoloLens will lose the connection, but continues scanning for and listing available networks.
If I then turn my hotspot back on, the method "await WiFiAdapter.ScanAsync()" will take some 20 seconds, then fails and throws an exception somewhat like "Operation aborted, ...TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess" (I made a screenshot showing the content of the exception).

[image: Thrown exception of ScanAsync()]

Without try/catch, this led to my async Task Scan() exiting without finally setting my boolean IsReady back to true, which then resulted in my App not scanning for available networks anymore. 
The problem is, that my current solution is nothing but a simple workaround which actually works, but which is not actually solving the issue I'm having with the ScanAsync method.

I just can't figure out why it behaves like this. A WiFiAdapter is available, so this probably is not the problem.
Is there a way to check if my established connection to my desired network is being lost (just like when I turn of my hotspot)?
Or is there a way to tell the "await ScanAsync" method to cancel earlier if it takes too long?
I'm glad for every idea of you guys!

Greetings
B.B.

-EDIT-

My complete class looks like this, and I instantiate it one time in another script where I then call the necessary functions.

```
using Assets;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Devices.WiFi;
using Windows.Networking.Connectivity;


namespace Assets
{
    public class UniversalWiFi : IWiFiAdapter
    {
        private bool Success { get; set; }
        private WiFiConnectionStatus MyConnectionStatus;
        private bool IsReady { get; set; }
        private bool InitialConnection { get; set; }
        private uint Signal { get; set; }
        private string Report { get; set; }
        private string DesiredSsid { get; set; }
        private string ConnectedSsid { get; set; }
        private WiFiAdapter MyWiFiAdapter { get; set; }
        private bool ReadyToConnect { get; set; }

        public UniversalWiFi()
        {
            InitialConnection = true;
            Success = false;
            IsReady = true;
            ReadyToConnect = true;
            Signal = 0u;
            DesiredSsid = "Desired SSID not yet defined";
            ConnectedSsid = string.Empty;
            Report = string.Empty;
        }

        public bool GetSuccess()
        {
            return Success;
        }

        public string GetNameOfConnectedSsid()
        {
            try
            {
                var connected = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile().WlanConnectionProfileDetails.GetConnectedSsid();
                if (connected != null)
                {
                    ConnectedSsid = connected;
                }
                else
                {
                    ConnectedSsid = string.Empty;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                ConnectedSsid = string.Empty;
            }
            return ConnectedSsid;
        }

        public uint GetSignal(string ssid)
        {
            DesiredSsid = ssid;
            return Signal;
        }

        private async Task InitiateGetAdapterAsync()
        {
            var result = await WiFiAdapter.FindAllAdaptersAsync();
            if (result.Count >= 1)
            {
                MyWiFiAdapter = result[0];
            }
            InitialConnection = false;
        }

        public async Task Scan()
        {
            if (IsReady)
            {       
                IsReady = false;
                uint signal = 0u;
                    if (MyWiFiAdapter == null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            await InitiateGetAdapterAsync();
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            MyWiFiAdapter = null;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            await MyWiFiAdapter.ScanAsync();

                            GenerateNetworkReport(MyWiFiAdapter.NetworkReport);

                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DesiredSsid) && DesiredSSIDExists(MyWiFiAdapter.NetworkReport))
                            {
                                signal = GetNetworkSignal(MyWiFiAdapter.NetworkReport, DesiredSsid);
                                var desiredNW = MyWiFiAdapter.NetworkReport.AvailableNetworks.Where(y => y.Ssid == DesiredSsid).FirstOrDefault();
                                if ((ConnectedSsid != DesiredSsid) && (desiredNW != null))
                                {
                                    if ((await MyWiFiAdapter.ConnectAsync(desiredNW, WiFiReconnectionKind.Manual)).ConnectionStatus == WiFiConnectionStatus.Success) //ReconnectionKind entspricht dem Häkchen "automatisch verbinden" in den Windows Einstellungen
                                    {                                                                                                                                //"Manual" da sich die HoloLens sonst teilweise über die App stellt und selbstständig verbindet
                                        Success = true;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Success = false;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Success = false;
                            }
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            string fail = e.ToString();
                            Success = false;
                        }
                    }
                IsReady = true;
                Signal = signal;
            }

        private bool DesiredSSIDExists(WiFiNetworkReport report)
        {
            var networks = new List<string>();
            foreach (var network in report.AvailableNetworks)
            {
                networks.Add(string.Format("SSID: {0} -- SignalBars: {1} -- Db: {2} -- Mac: {3}",
                    network.Ssid, network.SignalBars, network.NetworkRssiInDecibelMilliwatts, network.Bssid));
            }
            var match = networks.FirstOrDefault(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Contains(DesiredSsid));

            if (match != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private uint GetNetworkSignal(WiFiNetworkReport report, string ssid)
        {
            var network = report.AvailableNetworks.Where(x => x.Ssid.ToLower() == ssid.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
            if (network != null)
            {
                return network.SignalBars;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0u;
            }
        }

        private void GenerateNetworkReport(WiFiNetworkReport report)
        {
            var networks = new List<string>();
            foreach (var network in report.AvailableNetworks)
            {
                networks.Add(string.Format("SSID: {0} -- SignalBars: {1} -- Db: {2} -- Mac: {3}",
                    network.Ssid, network.SignalBars, network.NetworkRssiInDecibelMilliwatts, network.Bssid));
            }

            Report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, networks.ToArray());
        }

        public string GetNetworkReport()
        {
            return Report;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tested in my phone device, it works well. I don't know why `ScanAsync` method inboked after hotspot disable, do you call it manually? Can you show more code?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I added the code of my class

Comment: I found some wrong logic in `Scan` method that cause I have never get `MyWiFiAdapter` instance.

Comment: Useful to know someone else has the same problem with WiFiAdapter.ScanAsync() . And there's no documentation for ScanAsync() saying why it could fail. And the Exception (HRESULT: 0x80004004) (a.k.a., "There was an error") doesn't help either.

Comment: It's worse.  I have the original  "WiFiScan" that's part of the UWP example collection from Microsoft--I started from that originally--and now it is also failing, the same way, with the same exception.